# Not able to Authenticate using access token generated across different Machines

Tags: java, azure, oauth

I am trying to authenticate Azure SQL Database using access token, Problem is, the access token(and refresh token) is generated on the different machine and SQL server authentication java code is on another machine. My application on 2nd machine picks the refresh token from the properties file. I am able to get the access token using refresh token but not able to authenticate the Azure SQL DB using that. However, everything works fine if I do the whole process on the same machine.

**Are access token generated IP bound or machine bound?**

> Error: Database connection failed: Error message: Login failed for user ''. ClientConnectionId:321ad51b-77d5-4681-a162-d6c8afd477aa

Comment: Did you mean the whole process could work alone on the both machines, not on a machine you have added its address to the firewall of Azure SQL Database?

Comment: @PeterPan thanks for your response. Actually what I want to say is that I generated the access token on say machine A with some IP address and I am using that token on another machine, say machine B with some different IP address. I get above-mentioned error while trying to create a connection with SQL DB. Is access token generated is machine or IP address bound? Yes, I am able to create the Azure SQL DB connection with same token if doing the whole process on single machine. I have added the client IP address in to the azure SQL Database firewall.

Comment: @PeterPan, today I straight away created a sample application to test the access token based SQL authentication and I am able to create the connection successfully. (Token generated on machine A & used to authenticate DB at machine B). But, the issue still persists with my existing application where I am getting "Database connection failed: Error message: Login failed for user ''.". However, the same application works fine when the whole process is done on either of the machines. It's eating my mind and time, I am not able to figure out the issue with my existing application.

Comment: The issue has been resolved, it was due to wrong (pretty old) version of mssql JDBC jar.

Comment: You can post an answer to help everyone which get the similar issue about how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved, it was due to wrong (pretty old) version of MSSQL JDBC jar.

Answer (score 0):

Each user has a default database. When you connect to computer that's running Microsoft SQL Server, and you do not specify a login database, the default database is used. However, if the default database is unavailable at the time of the connection, you may not be able to connect